# How to solve Shared Preferences not working in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm using Shared Preferences in flutter , but it not working with me in vs code and andriod studio , after adding dependencies and import the package then try the app nothing happen when clicking on the button which it do the function.

------- this my code in home page --------

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_2/another_screen.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'another_screen.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Shared Preference',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Shared Preference'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    setData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text('Go Another Screen'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (_) => const AnotherScreen(),
            ));
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  setData() async {
    SharedPreferences _pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    _pref.setString('name', 'Rady');
    _pref.setInt('age', 19);
    _pref.setString('university', 'Rady');
    _pref.setInt('height', 19);
    _pref.setStringList('skills', ['Dart', 'Flutter']);
  }
}
```

----- the second page ------

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class AnotherScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnotherScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => AnotherScreenState();
}

class AnotherScreenState extends State<AnotherScreen> {
  String _name = '';
  int? _age;
  String _university = '';
  int? _height;
  List<String> _skills = ['', ''];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Info Screen'),
      ),
      body: DefaultTextStyle(
        style: const TextStyle(
            fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.black),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text('Name : $_name'),
              Text('Age : $_age'),
              Text('University : $_university'),
              Text('Height : $_height'),
              Text('Skill1 : ${_skills[0]}'),
              Text('Skill2 : ${_skills[1]}'),
              ElevatedButton(
                child: const Text('Get Data'),
                onPressed: () async {
                  await getData();
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  getData() async {
    SharedPreferences _pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      _name = _pref.getString('name')!;
      _age = _pref.getInt('age');
      _university = _pref.getString('university')!;
      _height = _pref.getInt('height');
      _skills = _pref.getStringList('skills')!;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Try getting the preferences, then setting state.

Comment: It seems you are saving all the data in one instance of shared preference. try using different instances for name, age, university, height, skills e.t.c

Answer (score 2):

Storing Data in shared preferences requires the `await` keyword

```
SharedPreferences _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await _prefs.setString('token', newToken);
```